# Android studio Instant Run restarts whole app every time

Tags: android, gradle, android-instant-run

I'm running Android Studio 2.3.2, gradle:2.3.2.
Every time I click Instant Run button the whole app restarts with this message in log:

> Instant Run applied code changes and restarted the app.     The app was
>   restarted since it uses multiple processes.

However, I do not use `android:process` anywhere in my code.
Moreover, there are no processes in Android Device Monitor or Android Monitor except main
 [one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYKns.png).

Comment: What OS version do you have in your Android phone?

Comment: see if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35680302/instant-run-doesnt-work-due-to-multiple-process) helps

Comment: @jayeshsolanki93 yeah that helped, thanks. I've removed some facebook related libraries.